# Integrating $\frac{1}{z\sin(z)}$ on a path

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the path integral of $\dfrac{1}{z\sin(z)}$ around $D_1(0)$? I've been trying to exploit residuals or use parametrization, but I can't come out of it.

What I actually need to do is to find the Laurent series of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant $\,D_1(0)=S^1=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=1\}\,$ , then we have one unique singularity within this path, in $\,z=0\,$:

$$f(z):=\frac{1}{z\sin z}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\csc z=\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7}{360}z^3+\ldots\right)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{7}{360}z+\ldots$$
and thus

$$Res_{z=0}(f)=0\Longrightarrow\oint\limits_{S^1}f(z)\,dz=0$$

**Added on request:** Taylor series for $\,z\,$ "close" to zero:

$$\csc z=\frac{1}{\sin z}=\frac{1}{\left(z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}-\ldots\right)}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{\left(1-\left(\frac{z^2}{6}-\mathcal O(z^4)\right)\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{z}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\mathcal O(z^4)\right)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{6}+\mathcal O(z^3)$$

We stop there since we're interested only in the coefficient of $\,z^{-1}\,$ ...Note that we're relying on

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\ldots\,\,\,,\,\,\text{for}\;\;|z|<1\;\;\text{(this is where the "close to zero" part kicks in)}$$

Comment: Yes I meant that, I didn't knew the expression of csc(z). Can you show me how to, eventually "manually" find the first non zero terms of the Laurent series of f(z)? That was actually my issue.

Comment: I added some stuff to my answer, @Temitope.A

Comment: Am I right to think that finding the coefficient 7/360 with this method is difficult?

Comment: I've also tried writing $c_k=1/2\pi i \int_{S^1} f(z)(z-a)^{(-k-1)}$ but then get stuck calculating the path integral with parametrization or using the residual theorem (i.e for a pole of order 1 $c_{-1}=\lim _{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)f(z)$)

Comment: Not really: only take more summands in the "basic" step: 

$$\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}\right)+\mathcal O(z^6)}=$$ $$1+\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}+\left(\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}\right)^2+ \ldots=$$
$$1+\frac{z^2}{6}-\frac{z^4}{120}+\frac{z^4}{36}-\ldots=1+\frac{z^2}{6}+ \frac{7}{360}z^4 +\ldots$$ Of course, all the above times $\,z^{-1}\,$...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I really appreciated your help!